# mongo aggregation calculate on each document with least value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

again hoping for help .. I would like to change my existing aggregation from "find only min and max for each type" to "find least value and calculate the difference for all others per type". But I currently have no idea how merge this together. I could query for both separately and do the calculation somehow in nodejs, but I would like to know how this should be done inside a mongo aggregation.

Given the following data

```
    { departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 500, req: 495 }
    { departement : 'D_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 422, req: 420 }
    { departement : 'F_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 600, req: 480 }

    { departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_7', offer: 900, req: 889 }
    { departement : 'D_TG', type : 'FLAT_7', offer: 601, req: 500 }
    { departement : 'F_TG', type : 'FLAT_7', offer: 600, req: 590 }

    { departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_4', offer: 601, req: 599 }
    { departement : 'D_TG', type : 'FLAT_4', offer: 755, req: 735 }
    { departement : 'F_TG', type : 'FLAT_4', offer: 600, req: 590 }
```

I am trying to find the difference of the "least" offer (for each type (eg. FLAT_1)) to all documents (of the same type).

Therefore, it would be necessary to

- for each type (eg. FLAT_1),
- find the least offer for this type (FLAT_1, in this case "offer: 422" from "departement : 'D_TG'")
- put this "least_offer and its least_offer_departement" to memory ...
- ... to be able to calculate the difference in ALL sets of same type (FLAT_1) like

  (this.docs.req-least offer)/(least offer/100) = percentual difference
- and print all documents incl the least_offer + least_offer_departement + difference

The expected result would finally be something like

```
{ type : "FLAT_1", least_offer : 422, least_offer_departement : "D_TG", departement : "C_TG", req: 495, diff : 17.29 }
{ type : "FLAT_1", least_offer : 422, least_offer_departement : "D_TG", departement : "F_TG", req: 480, diff : 13.74 }
{ type : "FLAT_1", least_offer : 422, least_offer_departement : "D_TG", departement : "D_TG", req: 420 , diff : -0.47 }

{ type : "FLAT_7", least_offer : 600, least_offer_departement : "F_TG", departement : "C_TG", req: 889, diff : 48.16 }
{ type : "FLAT_7", least_offer : 600, least_offer_departement : "F_TG", departement : "F_TG", req: 590, diff : -1.66 }
{ type : "FLAT_7", least_offer : 600, least_offer_departement : "F_TG", departement : "D_TG", req: 500, diff : -16.66 }

{ type : "FLAT_4", least_offer : 600, least_offer_departement : "F_TG", departement : "C_TG", req: 599, diff : -0.16 }
{ type : "FLAT_4", least_offer : 600, least_offer_departement : "F_TG", departement : "F_TG", req: 590, diff : -1.66 }
{ type : "FLAT_4", least_offer : 600, least_offer_departement : "F_TG", departement : "D_TG", req: 735, diff : 22.5 }
```

best regards, Simon

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. The existing aggregation is "grouping" by the type, and the results now have nothing really to do with the original documents. Even the percentages are unclear. Perhaps you should try explaining logically by saying what need to happen in the organization of data from it's "original state" until the "final desired state". If you don't understand all the aggregation pipeline terms and usage, then you are just confusing the issue by attempting to explain in terms of how to use them. Just explain what needs to happen to the data instead.

Comment: good morning, please apologize and lemme try to make it clearer.

What I want to achieve is basically, that for each type (e.g. type: "FLAT_1") the least offer (e.g. offer : 422) is taken and used as a base to calculate the difference against *all* higher requests (e.g. req: 590). The result should include the percentual difference between the two, and the departements. So in the result, the departement for the "offer" will always be the same, because its the one with the least offer. I hope this helps to make it clearer ? best regards

Comment: No it doesn't make it clearer. You're being asked to ["edit your question"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50744990/edit) and show "by example" how you expect to get to the result based on the source data. The words already in the question are just not clear. Adding a few more words is not making it any clearer. Take the time and make the question as clear as possible. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woohaa, I made it myself ..

The result is a a bit different than I initially wanted, but its giving me the information I wanted

Wanted to share my findings, maybe someone else can profit from it.

What I did :

```
    db.prices.aggregate ([
        // only offers/request > 0, sometimes we get 0 values ..
        {
            $match : {
                offer : {
                    $gt : 0,
                },
                req : {
                    $gt : 0,
                },
            }
        },
        // sort them, to be able to find least offer
        {
            $sort: {
                'type': 1,
                'offer': 1,
            },
        },
        // then group them by type, and and get the least offer and its departement
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$type',
                low_offer_departement: {
                    $first: '$departement'
                },
                low_offer: {
                    $first: '$offer'
                },
                // and push the current least offer and department to the document
                request : {
                    $push : {
                        departement : '$departement',
                        request: '$req',
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        // then we unwind "request subdocument" to create new documents, these are many ..
        {
            $unwind : '$request',
        },
        // now I can project and decide what I want to see in the result
        {
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                request : 1,
                type: '$_id',
                low_offer_departement : '$low_offer_departement',
                low_offer : '$low_offer',
                // for each document, I want the difference between the "lowest offer"
                // and the "current" request
                diff : {
                    $divide : [
                        {
                            $subtract : [
                                '$request.request', '$low_offer'
                            ]
                        }, {
                            $divide : [
                                '$low_offer', 100
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        // and finally I am only interested in results between 5 and 20%
        {
            $match : {
                diff : {
                    $gt : 5,
                    $lt : 20
                }
            }
        },
        // this sort does not seem to make sense, but the final output is in a
        // table in a terminal, and I dont want too much change/movement in there
        {
            $sort: {
                type: 1
            }
        }
    ]);
```

so before the unwind, we have the following result:

```
{ "_id" : "FLAT_7", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "request" : [ { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 590 }, { "departement" : "D_TG", "request" : 500 }, { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 889 } ] }
{ "_id" : "FLAT_4", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "request" : [ { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 590 }, { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 599 }, { "departement" : "D_TG", "request" : 735 } ] }
{ "_id" : "FLAT_1", "low_offer_departement" : "D_TG", "low_offer" : 422, "request" : [ { "departement" : "D_TG", "request" : 420 }, { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 495 }, { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 480 } ] }
```

which is fine so far, but I wanted the difference, so I decided to unwind and continue to format my output

after unwind and project stage, I have

```
{ "request" : { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 590 }, "type" : "FLAT_7", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "diff" : -1.6666666666666667 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "D_TG", "request" : 500 }, "type" : "FLAT_7", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "diff" : -16.666666666666668 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 889 }, "type" : "FLAT_7", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "diff" : 48.166666666666664 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 590 }, "type" : "FLAT_4", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "diff" : -1.6666666666666667 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 599 }, "type" : "FLAT_4", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "diff" : -0.16666666666666666 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "D_TG", "request" : 735 }, "type" : "FLAT_4", "low_offer_departement" : "F_TG", "low_offer" : 600, "diff" : 22.5 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "D_TG", "request" : 420 }, "type" : "FLAT_1", "low_offer_departement" : "D_TG", "low_offer" : 422, "diff" : -0.47393364928909953 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 495 }, "type" : "FLAT_1", "low_offer_departement" : "D_TG", "low_offer" : 422, "diff" : 17.298578199052134 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 480 }, "type" : "FLAT_1", "low_offer_departement" : "D_TG", "low_offer" : 422, "diff" : 13.744075829383887 }
```

so now I can filter the results to only get the really interesting stuff

which finally results in 2

```
{ "request" : { "departement" : "C_TG", "request" : 495 }, "type" : "FLAT_1", "low_offer_departement" : "D_TG", "low_offer" : 422, "diff" : 17.298578199052134 }
{ "request" : { "departement" : "F_TG", "request" : 480 }, "type" : "FLAT_1", "low_offer_departement" : "D_TG", "low_offer" : 422, "diff" : 13.744075829383887 }
```

I hope I didn't explain nonsens here and no wrong information, if so, bear with me, I am still a bloody bastard with mongo and aggregations ;)

best regards, Simon

Comment: Is it ok to accept my own answer ? hm, I hope so :p